# Prove that $\langle\sqrt2\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$. How many elements are in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]/\langle\sqrt2\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Prove that $\langle\sqrt{2}\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$. How many elements are in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]/\langle\sqrt{2}\rangle$ ?

I am unable to solve this. Please help me on this.

Comment: For the second part of the question, think of what happens when you take the quotient: $\sqrt{2}$ is taken to zero, along with all powers and integer multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ – in particular, the even numbers. What ring results from quotienting out the even numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck and in what context you have encountered the problem, i.e edit your post with this information
, so that someone can help you. Just stating 
a question like this then it is likely it will get closed.

Comment: In general, when dealing with prime or maximal ideals, it is often helpful to write it out in the language of domains and fields (and vice versa!)

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$\phi:\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi(a+b\sqrt2):=a\mod2$$

Prove this is ring homomorphism , find its kernel and apply the first isomorphism theorem.